# sql query to display a trailer record at the end of text file

Tags: sql

I want to display a trailer record at the end of records :
the spec is as follows

Trailer Record:

```
Field Name  Length     Begin       End    Type  Mandatory/Optional  Description
TYPE         2            1        2       AN      M                TR' = Trailer
RECORD COUNT 12           3        14      N       M                Record count not including Trailer Record
PROCESS DATE 8           15        22      N       M                (system date YYYYMMDD Format)
FILLER       278         23        300     AN      M                Space Filled
```

I am displaying this trailer record in a text file with already existing record that has about 1500 records. I am not able to get this at the end of the row. And I am using Count(*) and getdate() functions but not getting and output in the text file when I run it through batch(.bat) file.

Comment: Can you share your code for what you are attempting now. My gut tells me you need a UNION query, but it's tough to say without more info.

Comment: You can do it with a UNION but only if it can have the same columns as all of your data rows.  Any row set returned by SQL must all have the same columns.

Comment: I have posted in answer as 'Palak'  the code I used to display my already executed records. Now I want to display a trailer record with the above specs as a separate row at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [st]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[P_tnvin]    Script Date: 10/10/2016 13:35:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_tnvin]
 --@policyNum nvarchar(30)
 /*,@effectiveDate nvarchar(8)
 ,@VIN nvarchar(25)
 ,@lname1 nvarchar(40)
 ,@middle1 nvarchar(40)
 ,@fname1 nvarchar(40)
 ,@address1 nvarchar(50)
 ,@city nvarchar(35)
 ,@state nvarchar(2)
 ,@zip varchar(5)*/
 AS
 BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 Create Table TmpTNVINInfo
    (
    VINRecord char(300)
    )
INSERT INTO TmpTNVINInfo
SELECT
    (
        'VS' 
        + '12610' 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(30),LEFT(P.policyNum, 30)) 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(8),P.effectiveDate, 112) 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(25),LEFT(V.VIN, 25)) 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(40),LEFT(I.lname1, 40)) 
        + '   ' 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(20),LEFT(I.middle1, 20))
        + CONVERT(CHAR(40),LEFT(I.fname1, 40)) 
        + '   ' 
        + '         ' 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(50),LEFT(I.address1, 50)) 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(35),LEFT(I.city, 35)) 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(2),LEFT(I.state, 2)) 
        + CONVERT(CHAR(5),LEFT(I.zip, 5))
        + '                       '
    )storedprocedure
FROM
    [st].[dbo].[Policy] P
    JOIN
    [st].[dbo].[Auto] A
    ON
    P.policyID = A.policyID 
    JOIN
    [st].[dbo].[Vehicle] V
    ON
    A.autoID = V.autoID 
    JOIN
    [st].[dbo].[Insured] I
    ON
    P.insuredID = I.insuredID 
WHERE
    P.policyType = 1 --1=Auto
    AND
    P.status = 1 --1=Active
    AND
    P.policyNum NOT LIKE 'Q%'
END

/*SELECT * FROM TmpTNVINInfo

/****** Cleanup Temp Table *******/
DROP TABLE TmpTNVINInfo*/
```

This is the Code I used to display the records.